Redirection users after logging in via Azure AD B2C
I keep ending up at http://localhost:8080/?continue despite mentioning my preference.
.oauth2Login(login -> login                     
                .loginPage("/oauth2/authorization/azure")   
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome", true)  

Every time I need to go to my /welcome page manually.
Is there anyone who knows what is going on right now?

I added the welcome page as the default in the SecurityConfig class and successfully accessed it without manually entering the /welcome.
.defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome", true)

SecurityConfig.java :
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityfilterChain securityfilterChain(HttpSecurity http1) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
                        .authorizationEndpoint(authorization ->
                                authorization.baseUri("/oauth2/authorization")
                        )
                        .redirectionEndpoint(redirection ->
                                redirection.baseUri("/login/oauth2/code/*")
                        )
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome", true) 
                )
                .logout(logout ->
                        logout.logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
                );
        return http.build();
    }
}

WelcomeController.java :
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class WelcomeController {
    @GetMapping("/welcome")
    public String welcome() {
        return "welcome";
    }
}

welcome.html :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Welcome to Azure AD B2C</p>
</body>
</html>

Output :
It redirects to the Azure AD B2C login page, when I go to http://localhost:8080/ as shown below.

After logging in to Azure AD B2C, I was redirected to the /welcome page as shown below.

